# import a class from a file from another folder

Tags: python, file, selenium-webdriver, local-storage, sys

I have recently started working with Selenium and the page object model, the program works fine if I don't divide the files into folders class-tests_scripts. the flow of the program looks like this:

```
\parentDirectory
    \object
       -test.py
    \pages
       -login_page.py
```

this is the test script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pages.login_page import LoginPage
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initialize WebDriver (Chrome in this example)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open Adactin Hotel App login page
driver.get("http://adactinhotelapp.com/")

# Instantiate LoginPage
login_page = LoginPage(driver)

# Enter credentials using LoginPage methods
login_page.enter_username("------")
login_page.enter_password("------")

# Click login using LoginPage method
login_page.click_login()

# Wait for the page to load after login (example wait until the title changes)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("AdactIn.com - Search Hotel"))

# Perform further actions, assertions, or navigate to other pages using other Page Objects as needed

# Example: Get the current URL after login
current_url = driver.current_url
print("Current URL after login:", current_url)

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

this is the login_page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.username_field = (By.ID, "username")
        self.password_field = (By.ID, "password")
        self.login_button = (By.ID, "login")

    def enter_username(self, username):
        self.driver.find_element(*self.username_field).send_keys(username)

    def enter_password(self, password):
        self.driver.find_element(*self.password_field).send_keys(password)

    def click_login(self):
        self.driver.find_element(*self.login_button).click()
```

the error i am getting:

```
    from pages.login_page import LoginPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'
```

the other solutions i have tried:

```
1st alternative:from ..pages.login_page import LoginPage

2nd alternative:import sys
                sys.path.append('/Users/path/adactin/object/')  
                from pages.login_page import LoginPage
```

the errors i got:

```
alternative1 error:
    from ..pages.login_page import LoginPage
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

alternative2 error:
    from pages.login_page import LoginPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following as a simple hack (you tried something similar but excluded the "pages" directory):

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(Path("..")/"pages")
from login_page import LoginPage
```

Of course the other way would be to properly package your project, see for example:

1. https://betterscientificsoftware.github.io/python-for-hpc/tutorials/python-pypi-packaging/
2. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/